# multiprocessing

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Задача состоит в том что бы послать одновременно два запроса, тот запрос который вернет ответ первым должен этот ответ передать в главный процесс и завершиться, тот кто не успел передать запрос, должен умереть. Проблема в том, что не могу убить дочерний процесс из дочернего, так как он не знает о его существовании

```
def ds(topic):
    print(mqtt.mqtt_pub(message.domen, message.user_mqtt, message.password_mqtt, topic, "cmd1"))
    print (current_process().name)
    if current_process().name == '1':
        proc2.terminate()
    else:
        proc.terminate()
start_time = time.time()
proc = Process(target=ds, args=(topic1,), name='1')
proc2 = Process(target=ds, args=(topic2,), name='2')
proc.start()
proc2.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import multiprocessing, time

def ds(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = [5, 2]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=len(args))
    print(next(p.imap_unordered(ds, args)))
    p.close()
    print('end')
```

out

```
2
end
```